# How to save Python DataFrame without Index

Tags: python, dataframe, csv

```
import pandas as pd    
header=['Symbol']
df_sym=pd.DataFrame(symbols,columns=header)
df_sym.to_csv('symbols_list.csv',columns=header)
```

Works fine this way. But what if I don't want to write index?
I tried `df_sym=pd.DataFrame(symbols,index=False,columns=header)` but it returns error:

> Message=Index(...) must be called with a collection of some kind,
> False was passed

Answer (score 0):

Use the `index` parameter while writing to a CSV rather than when creating the DataFrame.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html